# How to modify a constant in a Delphi library file without changing the library file?

Tags: delphi, constants, delphi-10-seattle

I use a third party library for which i need to change a constant. I would like to customize the library without overwriting the file.
The pas file is a library file, not an inheritable class.

Currently i can achieve my goal by editing the file

```
unit libraryconstants;

interface

uses
  System.Types;

const
  constant1 = 'foo';
  constant2 = 32;
  constant3: Integer = 12;
  constant4: TSize = (cx: 32; cy: 32);
```

Somehow I need to change `constant4` like this:

```
constant4: TSize = (cx: 16; cy: 8);
```

I can edit libraryconstants.pas and save it, but as i update the library (because a new version is released) i will lose this change. Of course I can remind me to apply this change each time i update the library,  but I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Since the constant is not a published property i do not know how to achieve the desired result. I'd like to interfere with the library code as less as possible.

I am looking for a Delphi language "trick" i do not know.

Thanks.

Comment: That constant is stored in read only memory. At startup, e.g. in a unit initialization, set memory protection for the memory to be writeable. Modify the memory, restore memory protection.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - nice hack, even it's breaking all the rules...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan do you have a sample? Thanks.

Comment: I'd stay with patching the source instead of patching at runtime. You can let remind yourself via an Assert in an often-used code path.

Comment: Additionally you could ask the library vendor to turn `constant4` into a customizable variable. So the problem would go away sometime.

Comment: Not all constant stored separately in data, some const can be in code section

Comment: @Vasek This is a typed constant though. True constants would require source code to be changed.

Comment: @LaBracca Turns out I was wrong about memory protection. I've always assumed that Emba would place typed constants in read only memory. That's what happens in other languages. It seems that typed constants are actually just variables that the compiler stops you using as variables. This is really disappointing to me. On the other hand, it makes your task easier as my answer demonstrates.

Comment: Why don't you use **var** instead of **const**? I.e.
`var constant3: Integer = 12;` and `var constant4: TSize = (cx: 32; cy: 32);`

Comment: @gammatester it is not up to him to choose, he is using a third-party library.

Comment: @nil: He can edit the pas file.

Comment: @gammatester Yes, but he stated that he would like not to, if possible

Comment: Library is dll/bpl or direct pas files include?

Comment: Use version control with "vendor branches" (this is exactly its use case): http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was erroneously under the impression that typed constants are stored in read only memory, as they would be in other languages. That's not the case. So you can change the value of this typed constant quite easily by accessing it via a pointer.

```
PSize(@constant4).cx := 16;
PSize(@constant4).cy := 8;
```

Add this code to the initialization section of one of your units. You'll need to make sure that it runs early enough to effect the change before any code that depends on the constant is executed.

I think my misapprehension comes about through the knowledge that string literals are stored in read only memory. So I assumed that the same would be true for typed constants. I suspect that when the assignable typed constants "feature" was added, the compiler switch simply made the compiler reject writes to typed constants, rather than also moving them to read only memory.

Note that what I say about read only memory is true on the desktop compilers. I am not sure whether or not it is true on the mobile compilers. It may well be the case that this code fails with a runtime memory protection error on the mobile compilers. In which case you would need temporarily to alter the memory protection before writing to it.

Comment: This is really news. Thanks a lot, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Make a new UNIT:

```
unit libraryconstantspatch;

interface

implementation

uses System.Types, libraryconstants;

initialization

asm
        mov     eax,offset libraryconstants.constant4
        mov     [eax+offset TSize.cx],16
        mov     [eax+offset TSize.cy],8
end

finalization

end.
```

then list this unit in the USES statement AFTER the libraryconstants unit in your application.

Comment: Hmm, apparently I am. I can't believe that Emba got that wrong. Still, the asm is a bad idea. Use `TSize((@constant4)^).cx := 16; TSize((@constant4)^).cy := 8;`

Comment: And the reason for ASM is that if the constant is defined in the {$J-} state, you cannot alter it directly using PASCAL, but you can via ASM.

Comment: Er, the code in my previous comment shows how to do just that

Comment: I wouldn't call that "directly". "Directly" would be _constant4.cx:=16;_

Comment: You think that the asm is preferable? Really. What about cross platform?

Answer (score 0):

In project settings (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>):

```
Delphi compiler \ Compiling \ Syntax options
```

Change value of "**Assignable typed constants**" to True.
Then you can modify typed constants as regular variables:

```
constant4.cx := 16;
constant4.cy := 8;
```

Comment: Unless the original source contains a {$J-} compiler directive (or gets one in the future).

Comment: Enabling assignable typed constants for the entire project is absolutely not to recommended. This is a setting that only exists by accident and for compatibility with old code. You absolutely should not be using it.

Comment: @David It is not recommended, because changing constants - is bad idea. But it is asked in the question. If i have to choose between hacking (changing memory protection status -> not only that constant will be writable, ...) & compiler settings, i prefer to change compiler options for the project.

Comment: You only need to change the protection temporarily. It can be restored. And as it happens I was wrong about protection. Typed constants are not protected. But anyway, even if they were, enabling typed constants is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: do not change the constant, change the method.

Examine what method (procedure or function) using the constant, then "overload" the method using new constant.

If it is in a class, just inherit the class, and modify only the method, using new name, like procedure 'aMethod_size2'. Name size2 is giving sign about it.

This is usual practice as I know.